# How does receiving application knows which serialization mechanism has been used?

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers, kafka-consumer-api, json-serialization

I am receiving bytes of data onto a kafka topic and those bytes can be sent (by an application) by using plain `Java Serialization` or `JSON serialization` or `protocol buffer`.

So, now when my application reads those bytes from kafka topic, how does it know which Serilization technique was used, which can be: `Java Serialization`, `JSON Serialization`, `Protocol Buffer`.

Is there a way to check this? Does "Serialization format" differ by these different mechanisms?

Any information to understand this would be of great help.

Comment: Yes, the format will differ drastically.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Thanks for your comment. However, could you provide some insight on other part of question viz: identifying serialization format?

Comment: Not really.  Though you should probably just stick to one serialization format for your whole application, in which case it won't be an issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

The serialization technique must be agreed/defined between the sender and the receiver.

It must be the contract between the two parts.